# Sending mail with an android app

Tags: android, email

I would like to know how to make an android app send a mail with a static text when i click a button for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bounce the message off a web script and have php do the sending for you.  It's a hybrid approach android/php, but it allows you to have a little more flexibility and would offload any strains on email sending to the server and not android.